# iOS why is UIView displayed correctly only after reloading UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, layout, uiview

I am trying to insert a lot of views into `UITableViewCell`.
I add view and calculate required constants. And I can't resolve one problem. Inner labels can be bigger than one line and when `UITableView` only initialized it didn't displays correctly: some cropped labels, wrong height and etc.

[image]

But when I reload tableview or scroll to bottom elements and scroll back to incorrect one cell all views displays correctly.

[image]

**EDITED**

Example: I have UITableViewCell. Every cell contains number of attributes(separate views). Each attribute view has title(gray text) and attribute value(single view again). Each attribute value view may have different height. And I assume height doesn't calculates right at the first time.

When I build UITableViewCell firstly I build all of attribute views and after that I add each view to Cell and calculate constants.

Comment: Make sure that you have set y co-ordinate of UITableView Properly.

Comment: Did you implement the the UITableView delegate `
- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` where you compute the height of the indicated row (if possible)? It will certainly make you call `NSString -boundingRectWithSize:` method on your labels to be able to evaluate the needed height of your cell from the beginning.

Comment: Please add some code which you have done for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve problem.

When I got UITableViewCell it frame has width 325 but tableView frame width is 375. Because of this inner views were build incorrect way. Now I just set contentView of Cell to tableView frame.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "ListCell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? ListViewCell

    cell!.contentView.frame = tableView.frame

    // additional setup

    return cell!
}
```